# Ubuntu 16.10 NVIDIA OpenCL?

Tags: nvidia, 16.10, opencl

I have a brand new install of Ubuntu 16.10.  I want to test against the NVIDIA version of OpenCL (I need portability across devices).  So, I installed the CUDA toolkit via

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit clinfo
```

However, when I run `clinfo` all I get is:

```
Number of platforms:            0
```

I have also tried to find the `libOpenCL.so` shared object, but I cannot find it anywhere. Any insight?

**EDIT**

The output of `sudo lshw -C display`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
       vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master rom
       configuration: driver=vboxvideo latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:e0000000-e0ffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

You will notice that this is a virtual machine.  This is where I prototype everything and have done previous work with CUDA before on older OS (e.g 14.04).

Comment: Hardware (CPU/GPU)?

Comment: @PatrickNegus NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 GPU.  I would expect `clinfo` to return 1 platform regardless of the device though.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C display` Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: I'm sorry, I am unable to help you. I was under the impression that you were trying to utilize the NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970 GPU directly (bare metal). I've never even considered trying to use software designed for the Nvidia GPU on a VirtualBox Graphics Adapter. Perhaps someone else will chime in! Best of luck!

Comment: @ElderGeek yea, I have a machine with the nvidia card but it is still 14.04 and I don't want to upgrade until I know the newer OS will work the same. I mainly just want to get OpenCL to recognize the nvidia platform.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using the NVidia proprietary driver. Then installing nvidia-opencl-dev and nvidia-opencl-icd-xxx where xxx correspond to the driver version you are running should be fine. That worked for me on 16.04